# difference between rake db:autoupgrade and rake db:automigrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-datamapper

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Datamapper. Could anyone please tell me what is the difference between `rake db:autoupgrade` and `rake db:automigrate` in datamapper. Because in my application I have used model A and model B as follows:

```
 class A
    includes DataMapper::resource
    property :id, Serial
    belongs_to :B, :required=>true
  end

  class B
    includes DataMapper::resource
    property :id, Serial
    has n, :As
  end
```

Then after changing `:required => false` in the model A while doing `rake db:autoupgrade` no change happens to the A table in database but while doing `rake db:automigrate` the following error is coming:

```
 cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Answer (score 1):

if there a foreign key constant you can not delete the associated table. what else you can do is `rake db:drop` and create the table again.

Comment: The problem is solved now. First I take mysql dump of that table. Then I dropped the table and modified that field in dump file by changing it to deafult null. Then I did rake db:autoupgrade and import the modified table dump again to the database.